# How to Update 2 Columns on the Base of One Condition in SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

I have used the following query to update my users table in mysql

```
update users set user_likes = 
(CASE WHEN like_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' 
AND dislikes_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' 
THEN (user_likes +1) ELSE user_likes END)
WHERE post_id = '2221'
```

This works fine for me but I also want to update the likes_by_users like this

```
likes_by_users = CONCAT(likes_by_users,' ','user_name')
```

I have tried to do it like this

```
update users set user_likes = 
(CASE WHEN like_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' 
AND dislikes_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' 
THEN (user_likes +1), likes_by_users = CONCAT(likes_by_users,' ','user_name')  
ELSE user_likes END)
WHERE post_id = '2221'
```

But it does not work at all.
I do not want to check the condition again but if the above mention condition is true then it should update the two columns (user_likes) and (likes_by_users) not only (user_likes), and if the condition false then it should not update any column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with help of a WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE `users`
SET `user_likes` = `user_level` + 1, `likes_by_users` = CONCAT(`likes_by_users`, ' ', 'user_name')
WHERE `post_id` = '2221'
AND `like_by_users` NOT LIKE '%user_name%' 
AND `dislikes_by_users` NOT LIKE '%user_name%'
```

Comment: I need to apply this only on a single record. I have updated my question. You can check now and have more brief idea about my problem.

Comment: Just add the id of the post, it'n not harder thatn that.

Comment: That is really great. Thanks for this query solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
update users
Set user_likes = IF(like_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' AND dislikes_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%',(user_likes + 1), user_likes),
  likes_by_users = IF(like_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%' AND dislikes_by_users NOT LIKE '%user_name%', CONCAT(likes_by_users,' ','user_name'), user_likes)
WHERE post_id = 2221
```

Comment: But I said, I do not want to check the condition twice because It will slow down the process. I have to update 2 columns on the base of one condition, so I am trying to find the way that if the condition is true then update these two columns and if the condition is false then do nothing.